# CScript/WScript Prevent an error from being blocking

Tags: vbscript, automation, wsh

Currently, WScript pops up message box when there is a script error. These scripts are called by other processes, and are ran on a server, so there is nobody to dismiss the error box.

What I'd like is for the error message to be dumped to STDOUT, and execution to return the calling process. Popping as a MSGBox just hangs the entire thing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you should be running Script batch jobs:

```
cscript //b scriptname.vbs
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript/9062764#9062764

Answer (score 2):

Don't use WScript; use CScript.  At the Windows command prompt, type the following to display help.

```
cscript //?
```

I suggest the following:

```
cscript //H:CScript
```

This will make CScript your default scripting interpreter.  CScript prints messages to the console (i.e., stdout) as you desire.  (It does not use dialog windows.)
You may also want to try the //B switch, but I can't tell if that has to be run per-script or not.  If it is a persistent, one-time switch like the //H switch is, then this may work for you; if not, you may need to modify all of your remote programs to include it.  From the information you provided, I think just changing the default interpreter (//H) will do what you want.

You will also need to add some sort of error handling to keep the script from terminating on an error.  In Visual Basic Scripting Edition, the easiest thing to do if you just want to ignore errors is to add the following to the top of your script.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(VS.85).aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WScript.Echo` instead of `MsgBox`. And also run the script using `Cscript` instead of `Wscript`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated what language you're using. If you're using VBScript, you can write an error handler using the [On Error...](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.apiref.doc/c_vbscript_err_hndlng.htm) statement. If you're using JScript, you can use a [try {} catch (x) {}](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp) block.

Answer (score 0):

don't do this:

> vbscript:
> On error resume next
>
> english:
> "when you have an error, ignore it & just keep going".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put your script code in a Sub - e.g. `DoWork` - and code your script something like:

```
On Error Resume Next

DoWork

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    If "CSCRIPT.EXE" = UCase( Right( WScript.Fullname, 11 ) ) Then
        WScript.StdErr.Write Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Else
        WScript.Echo Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End If
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

Private Sub DoWork

    ... your code ...

End Sub
```

In this way, when you run your script using `cscript //b`, and it fails, you'll get an error message output to stderr and the caller will receive a non-zero errorlevel.