# My Visual Basic scripts Open instead of running

Tags: python, vbscript

I've written a small Python script to test my Visual Basic scripts function correctly before deploying them -

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cmd /c MyScript.vbs")
```

Rather than running the Visual Basic script, my script opens in Sublime Text (the default program).

How can I run the scripts rather than Opening them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of these, *cscript* is more appropriate for a console application.

```
subprocess.call("cmd /c wscript MyScript.vbs")
```

or

```
subprocess.call("cmd /c cscript MyScript.vbs")
```

An excellent answer as to what the difference is can be found here: [Difference between wscript and cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript)

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: one is more appropriate for a "windowed" app, the other for console. i amended the answer with a link to a thorough explanation