# Batch File Run VBScript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am a newbie in the programming. I am wondering what the difference is between below two method of kicking off a VBScript. Both of them work on my machine.

`call "C:\script.vbs"`

`cscript "C:\script.vbs"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, people compare cscript with wscript, the difference is explained here:

[Difference between wscript and cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript)

"Call" calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program.

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/call.mspx?mfr=true

[CALL command vs. START with /WAIT option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257571/call-command-vs-start-with-wait-option)

In Windows, if you are running an automated program written in several batch scripts, you'll want to use "call".

Comment: I understand both pairs, wscript/cscript and call/start; but my question is whether there is a different between call script.vbs and cscript script.vbs

Comment: @lovechillcool OK, if so, based on my knowledge, if there is a message box in your vbs (e.g.: wscript.echo("OK")), using call will show a windows message box, using cscript will show the message in the parent console.

Comment: It should be noted that this is basically because call will use the default scripting host which is wscript not because call does that. call on something different than a batch is more or less the same as not using call

Comment: And also, if use cscript, ugly header would show up so I used `cscript //nologo` to suppress it; call doesn't show the header in the first place.