# How to execute vbs file in java, which directory contains spaces

Tags: java, vbscript

Im currently coding a program, but i need to make it execute a vbs file. TempDir.vbs. However, the directory to this file contains spaces.
Unfortunally, all other topics dont work when the directory contains spaces.
In my case:
`C:\\Users\\"the user"\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup`

the code im currently using is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript.exe " + "\"\"\"" + path + "\"\"\"" + "TempDir.vbs");
```

So, how can i execute the file TempDir.vbs.

Comment: Please provide the code by which you're attempting to execute the VBS from Java.  As long as the path is properly quoted and/or escaped, there is no reason why this can't work.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully it is better now. not reallu sure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`Runtime.exec(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29), use [`Runtime.exec(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
    "wscript.exe",
    path + "TempDir.vbs"
});
```

As mentioned in a comment to a now deleted answer by ziesemer, if the .vbs file is a console script, you might need to use `cscript.exe`. See this for explanation: [Difference between wscript and cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript)