# Activate Windows License

Tags: windows, powershell, wsh

When I use `slmgr /skms <URL> | cmd` command in PowerShell it shows me a pop up that I must press the ok button after that I run `slmgr /ato | cmd` and again shows me another pop up that I press the ok button.

I don't want to press the ok button manually, can anybody help me if there is a solution for it, please?

I just disabled the [uac](/questions/tagged/uac) in windows, but it does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `cscript`. By just executing a vbs script file, output gets sent to dialog boxes, which need your interaction.

Using `cscript`, the desired output gets printed to your current stdout:

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs /ato
```

That doesn't have anything to do with UAC and you might consider re-activating it.

---

### But why is that?

`slmgr` is not a *command* nor is it an executable in windows. It's a script file written in VBScript. VBScript is a kind-of scripting version of VB, So it's [good for your peace of mind not to deal with it too much](https://www.zdnet.com/article/100-million-and-one-reasons-to-hate-vb-and-vbscript/).

If you type in `slmgr /skms`, what windows does is looking for a file named slmgr in its search paths (`%PATH%`), finding `C:\Windows\System32\slmgr.vbs` and deciding that, as its a `.vbs` file, executing `wscript.exe` with the file path and your arguments as parameter is the right thing to do.

WScript is the default interpreter for vbs files and just interprets the file and executes its code. On the other hand, there is `cscript` for *console* scripts.

If the author of the `.vbs` file decides to write a message to the user of their script, they usually use a statement like

```
Wscript.Echo "Hello, World!"
```

**And thats where  your confusion starts**:
Executing this script in *cscript* means that `Hello, World!` is written to the console. (That's what you want to do)
Executing the same script using *wscript* renders a message box with a OK button. You can easily reproduce it yourself by creating a vbs file with the above statement.

The difference between cscript and wscript is also discussed in this question:
[Difference between wscript and cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678441/difference-between-wscript-and-cscript)

Comment: Hi Clijsters, I'm a beginner at Powershell and Script, is it possible to give me more detailed guidance?

Comment: Of course, I just added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: setting the server:  `cscript //Nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms kms.stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I think you mean `wscript.exe` not `vscript.exe`, there is no such executable. Both `cscript.exe` and `wscript.exe` are part of the Windows Scripting Host.

Comment: @user692942 of course, thanks for the hint. I stopped using windows several years ago. Thats why I couldnt verify my snippets 1st hand