# How to loop while Msgbox is open?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, vbscript

I have a developed a script that at some point in the code calls a VBScript that minimizes all current open Windows and displays a MsgBox. The script is set to run at startup so, other applications are also starting while the user logs in to the machine.

Batch code calling VBS – >

```
cscript //nologo lckPNot.vbs
```

lckPNot.vbs – >

```
set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.MinimizeAll
x=MsgBox ("Message Here.",0+48,"Notification")
```

The `objShell.MinimizeAll` successfully minimizes all open current Windows however I face an issue once a window opens up after the `objShell.MinimizeAll` and before the user provides his input to the MsgBox.

i.e. I need a way to say the following:

```
while MsgBox = Visible
Minimize All
Loop
```

If the above is not possible, I can also try to use the loop in the batch code itself, i.e.
while lckPNot.vbs = Running
Call KillProcesses.bat
Loop

Where `KillProcesses.bat` is another batch that kills all open tasks (instead of minimize) at a given point.

How can that be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CScript/WScript Prevent an error from being blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89465/cscript-wscript-prevent-an-error-from-being-blocking)

Comment: Well, it's a start. Basically this would allow me to complete execution when the msgbox appears but i still need a way to detect if the message box is closed or still open, ideas ?

Comment: What the duplicate is telling you is the `MsgBox()` blocks code execution, you need to use `cscript.exe` to avoid GUI elements blocking the script.

Answer (score 1):

Run the MsgBox in a separate process and check for that. Like this:

WaitOnMsgBox.vbs

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oShApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

Function ProcessExist(Exe,File)
  ProcessExist = False
  On Error Resume Next
  Set oProcesses = oWMI.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process")
  For Each oProcess In oProcesses
    If InStr(oProcess.CommandLine,Exe) Then
      If InStr(oProcess.CommandLine,File) Then
        ProcessExist = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next
  On Error Goto 0
End Function

oShell.Run ".\MsgBox.vbs ""Message Here"" 0+48 ""Notification""",1,False

Do While ProcessExist("\WScript.exe","\MsgBox.vbs")
  oShApp.MinimizeAll
  WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
```

MsgBox.vbs

```
On Error Resume Next
Message = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
Icon    = Eval(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
Title   = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
On Error Goto 0
MsgBox Message,Icon,Title
```